# Why do these Array casting and deinc/inc produce the wrong numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, casting

I have been experimenting with type casting and arrays in Javascript

I was expecting the following code to output

string(4)
number(5)
number(3)
number(3)
number(5)

Could anyone explain why it doesn't?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 0;
function pLog(arg) {
    console.log(++counter + ": " + typeof(arg) + "(" + arg + ")");
}

var x = ["4"];

pLog(x[0]);     //string(4)

pLog(++x[0]);   //number(5)
pLog(--x[0]);   //number(4)

pLog(x[0]--);   //number(4)
pLog(x[0]++);   //number(3)
</script>
```

Comment: Because operator increment/decrement  is converted types to number

Comment: You need to read about difference between `++x` and `x++`. `++x` increments before return, `x++` increments after value is returned, so you see old value when you log it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var x = ["4"];
```

An array which has "4" at index 0.

```
(x[0]);
```

Item at index 0 is a string which equals "4" so output is: `string(4)`

```
(++x[0]);
```

Increment item at index 0 so javascript implicitly converts it to a number and then increments it so the output is: `number(5)`

```
(--x[0]);
```

Decrement item at index 0 which is 5 from previous step so output is: `number(4)`

Note that in this step no implicit conversion was needed anymore because the conversion already occurred in the the previous step where I mentioned it.

```
(x[0]--);
```

Get the value at index 0 and then decrement it so the output is: `number(4)`

The decrement is then done so the item at index 0 is 3 now.

```
(x[0]++);
```

Get the value at index 0 and then increment it so the output is: `number(3)`

The increment is then done so the item at index 0 is 4 now.

if you were to execute this statement now:

```
console.log(typeof(arg) + "(" + arg + ")");
```

The output will be: `number(4)`

---

I think the confusion comes from `++x` and `x++`

`++x` means increment the value of x **BEFORE** processing the current statement.

`x++` means increment the value of x **AFTER** processing the current statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
//string(4) number(5) number(3) number(3) number(5)
var x = ["4"];
pLog(x[0]);     //string(4)  // 

// ++x[0] convert string "4" to number 4, then add 1
pLog(++x[0]);  //number(5)  
// ++x[0] increments first, then returns the value 5
pLog(--x[0]);  //number(4)  
// --x[0] decrements first, then returns the value 4

pLog(x[0]--);  //number(4)  
// x[0]-- returns the value 4 first, then deduct 1 (the value now is 3!)
pLog(x[0]++);  //number(3)  
// x[0]++ returns the current value 3 first, then add 1 (the value now is 4!)
```